# Accessing java variable from native code via JNI giving junk value

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I'm creating a video player in android. In my android side of the code i have a toggle button for play/pause state. If plafFlag=0, then the video needs to be paused (playFlag is a variable in java part of the code).

In the native side of the code i'm trying to access the value of this playFlag each before each time a frame is displayed onto the screen.

Below is my java part the code:

```
public class myPlayer extends Activity {
    public int playFlag;
   .
   .
   .
   .
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.player);
          final ToggleButton playFlagBtn=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

         playFlagBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(playFlagBtn.isChecked()){
                    playFlag=0;
                }
                else{
                    playFlag=1;
                }
            }
        });
```

From this **OnCreate** function itself i have called the native code where i'm trying to access **playFlag** variable.

Below is the code snippet using which i'm accessing the **playFlag** variable:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/example/my_decoder/myPlayer");  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"MYAPP","reference to class obatined",NULL);

 jfieldID fidInt=(*env)->GetFieldID(env,cls,"playFlag","I");
 __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"MYAPP","fid obtained",NULL);

 int Flag=0;

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"MYAPP","Before fetching flag value",NULL);
playFlag=(*env)->GetIntField(env,jobj,fidInt);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"MYAPP","Initial value of playflag=%d",playFlag);
```

The above native code snippet doesnt give an error. The value is fetched, but it seems like some junk value.

In the logcat i get output like:

```
03-08 11:21:32.627: D/MYAPP(31220): Initial value of playflag=1085053248
```

The main intention here is to pause the decoding process if the value of the fetched flag is 0., otherwise continue to decode the frames and render it on the screen. Hence for me it is very important to fetch the right value of the flag from the java part of the code.

Can anyone please explain where i'm going wrong. Or if there is another way to do it.

Waiting for some replies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you create one variable in the native code and set the value of this native variable using the JNI from the activity...

Comment: Good idea but the problem is once the control is transfer to the native part of the code, only after decoding and displaying all the frames the control would come out of the code. Hence if i modify the native variable in my activity the same should be reflected back to the native variable. And i think that is possible only by calling a native code by passing this value. Or if there is a way out pls suggest.

Comment: In this case you would have to pass java object containing the flag value to the native layer.. following link might help https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/g5aZwumKvJI

Comment: Make sure `jobj` is actually an instance of the class you think it is -- in JNI it's easy to get things crossed up.  One thing to try would be to replace your `FindClass` call with `GetObjectClass(env, jobj)` and see if the `GetIntField` call still succeeds.  Also, make sure you're using the CheckJNI feature -- see http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking .