# How to access values from c++ to java in android

Tags: java, android, c++

I am importing a c++ based project(or library) in my android app.I used NDK for this purpose.I succeed with embedding c++ in java.Now i need to pass values to and from c++ and java.Can any one suggest how to access information(text,images,or videos) from c++ processed project to my android project.Expecting simple tutorials..

Comment: Why is this http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted no use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access Text(strings), arrays, integer data from android to c++ using JNI.

Eg. Android Function:

```
public native setString(String arg);
```

The above string arg can be accessed using JNI in c/c++ code as shown below:

C function:

```
char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, arg, 0);
```

C++ function dont pass the env as a parameter.

Similarly Other elements from Android can be accessed in c/c++ using the **jobject** class of the JNI.

However to access android variables from c/c++ you either need to return control from the c/c++ function to android or you can call an android function from c/c++ function where you can set values of android functions. This example you can find in below link:

[Accessing java variable from native code via JNI giving junk value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287926/accessing-java-variable-from-native-code-via-jni-giving-junk-value)

Good example of using picture data can be obtained from android-ndk sample programs(plasma app in sample programs).

Comment: but how can i access a data that might accessed by c++ from remote to my java

Comment: your answer is telling accessing a data from android to c++.But my question is reverse

Comment: In the link i have provided above, there is a java variable/flag that is being set/reset from the c/c++ code, this inturn means that you are able to access the java/android variables from c/c++.